# What is the ruling of gold teeth implanting (for men)?

Tags: halal-haram, men, human-body, gold

As an Islamic rule, it is Haram (forbidden) for men to wear the gold (as a ring or necklace). I was wondering if the implanting of gold teeth has the same ruling or it is permissible?
(As some dentists use/implant gold to repair the teeth … )

Answer (score 2):

Use of gold permitted **if there are no alternatives**. We have a narration in tirmidhi where the Prophet acceded a male to use gold.

> ‘Urfujah ibn As‘ad (may Allah be pleased with him) who said: My nose was cut off on the day of (the battle of) al-Kulaab during the Jaahiliyyah, so I had a nose made of silver, but it began to smell bad, so the **Messenger of Allah (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) told me to get a nose made of gold**.

Narrated by at-Tirmidhi, 1770; classed as saheeh by Shaykh al-Albaani (may Allah have mercy on him) in Saheeh at-Tirmidhi

Comment: In the case of teeth nowadays, there surely are very common and cheaper alternatives. So gold CANNOT be allowed.

Comment: Your answer doesn't quote the above hadith. So I feel your answer does injustice.

Comment: You can suggest the edit. Oryou should mention the ahadees i have mentiooned because as of now it seems like you are saying it is ok to have gold teeth.

Comment: Come on " **if you don't find alternatives**"

Comment: Yes, please highlight that in you answer, instead of highlighting the allowed part. Answer should be clear with no ambiguity

Answer (score 0):

**All praise be to Allah.**
Gold in any form is forbidden for men because the hadees stating the hurmat of gold for men does not specify any specific use, it just specifies that gold is haram for men.

> ‘Ali, may Allaah be pleased with him, reported that the Prophet of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) took a piece of silk in his right hand and a piece of gold in his left, and said: "These are forbidden for the males of my ummah." (reported by al-Nisaa’i and Abu Dawud).

Also another hadees about how angry Prophet got on this matter:

> ‘Abdullah ibn ‘Abbaas reported that the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) saw a gold ring on a man’s hand. He took it off and threw it aside, saying, "Would any of you take a burning coal and hold it in his hand?" When the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) had gone away, someone said to the man, "Take your ring and benefit from it (i.e., sell it)." He said, "No, by Allaah, I will not take it after the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) has thrown it away." (reported by Muslim, no. 2090).

May Allah guide us all to the right path.

Comment: Sk. Utheymeen says if it's essential then it's OK as per fatwa of IslamQA

Comment: @Preordainment , yes that's general knowledge that necessity overrides the rulings. Like if its neccessary for you to keep drinking water because of some disease, you will not fast.